# How to launch Hello World Flutter on Desktop from Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio-3.0, flutter-desktop

I am trying out flutter value proposition of multi platforming.

I am on Android Studio.

Hello world works on Android.

Hello world is not launched on Iphone Emulator even though it is shown in the drop down.

I don't see anything to launch the app in a desktop where i can resize the window at will

I don't see anything either to launch the app in the browser.

Any help? Especially for the desktop and web .. The iphone emulator is probably a setting.

I am on Android Studio 3.3.2 and XCode 10.1

Comment: What is the output of flutter doctor -v ? do you have the iOS toolchain installed. Also check flutter devices and make sure it is picking up the device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter for desktop is in very early stages, [as described on the Flutter wiki](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Desktop-shells); it won't work out of the box. If you want to experiment with it, you'll need to [manually add desktop support to your project](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/blob/master/Quick-Start.md).

Similarly, Flutter for web is [a technical preview that requires extra setup to try out](https://flutter.dev/web).